# Javascript RegExp with two words

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find out how this works, but I'm not able to find out how to do this.

In my script there are two words it is starting with word open- and the second part is variable. I need to create regexp and than separate the second word.

I'm not javascript pro.

Comment: trust me. You need not have to be a pro to do this.

Comment: Or even give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You should use regex groups to find your word:

```
var str = 'open-someinterestingstring';
var matches = str.match(/^open-(\w+)/);

console.log(matches[1]);
```

Usefull information at [Mozilla Developers Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)